# What is output buffering in PHP?

Tags: php, output-buffering

What is output buffering and why would you use it in PHP?

Answer (score 301, accepted):

[Output Buffering for Web Developers, a Beginner’s Guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20101216035343/http://dev-tips.com/featured/output-buffering-for-web-developers-a-beginners-guide):

> Without output buffering (the default), your HTML is sent to the browser in pieces as PHP processes through your script. With output buffering, your HTML is stored in a variable and sent to the browser as one piece at the end of your script.
>
> Advantages of output buffering for Web developers
>
> - Turning on output buffering alone decreases the amount of time it takes to download and render our HTML because it's not being sent to the browser in pieces as PHP processes the HTML.
> - All the fancy stuff we can do with PHP strings, we can now do with our whole HTML page as one variable.
> - If you've ever encountered the message "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output)" while setting cookies, you'll be happy to know that output buffering is your answer.

Comment: +1. Here's another helpful link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php - also helpful when dealing with a function that echos a value that you'd rather store in a variable.

Comment: Is really everything buffered up to the end, or will the page just come in chunks if I have a reeeeally long page?

Comment: @zedoo if you start output buffering with `ob_start()`, *really everything* is buffered. there is an optional second parameter to `ob_start()`, `int $chunk_size`, which, if set, will cause the buffer to be flushed after any output call which causes the buffer's length to equal or exceed this size.

Comment: In what specific way can output buffering be the answer to the "Cannot modify header information" error? Surely you can't just turn it on and leave it like that for everything else right?

Comment: If you get "Warning: Cannot modify header information" , that means you need to audit your code first as enabling output buffering is a fix of the symptom and not the cause.  Something is writing before it's turn.  So I disagree, but not enough to bump the answer down.

Comment: I am using ob_start() to workaround a "set cookie" issue and outputting an XML document in the last line of my code. The XML outputs to the page as expected but I was wondering if it is a best practice to call ob_end_flush() at the end of the script.

Comment: I see only adventages of using buffering, so why It is not enabled by default in php?

Comment: I am using yii2 the ob_start(); solved my problem, I was getting this error. 'An Error occurred while handling another error:
exception 'yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException' with message 'Headers already sent in /var/www/html/frontend/controllers/Student_invoiceController.php on line 234.' in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366'

Answer (score 72):

[Output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) is used by PHP to improve performance and to perform a few tricks.

- You can have PHP store all output into a buffer and output all of it at once improving network performance.
- You can access the buffer content without sending it back to browser in certain situations.

Consider this example:

```
<?php
    ob_start( );
    phpinfo( );
    $output = ob_get_clean( );
?>
```

The above example captures the output into a variable instead of sending it to the browser. output_buffering is turned off by default.

- You can use output buffering in situations when you want to modify headers after sending content.

Consider this example:

```
<?php
    ob_start( );
    echo "Hello World";
    if ( $some_error )
    {
        header( "Location: error.php" );
        exit( 0 );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Same question here as for Ax: isn't starting output buffering without turning it back off later, going to make your script run into all kinds of problems?

Comment: Buffer is flushed when you call one of the flush methods (e.g. `ob_flush()` or `ob_end_flush()`). Contents of the buffer are also flushed when your script ends, abruptly or otherwise so there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 37):

I know that this is an old question but I wanted to write my answer for visual learners. I couldn't find any diagrams explaining output buffering on the worldwide-web so I made a diagram myself in Windows `mspaint.exe`.

If output buffering is turned off, then `echo` will send data immediately to the Browser.

[image]

If output buffering is turned on, then an `echo` will send data to the output buffer before sending it to the Browser.

[image]

**phpinfo**

To see whether Output buffering is turned on / off please refer to phpinfo at the core section. The `output_buffering` directive will tell you if Output buffering is on/off.

[image] 
In this case the `output_buffering` value is 4096 which means that the buffer size is 4 KB. It also means that Output buffering is turned on, on the Web server.

**php.ini**

It's possible to turn on/off and change buffer size by changing the value of the `output_buffering` directive. Just find it in `php.ini`, change it to the setting of your choice, and restart the Web server. You can find a sample of my `php.ini` below.

```
; Output buffering is a mechanism for controlling how much output data
; (excluding headers and cookies) PHP should keep internally before pushing that
; data to the client. If your application's output exceeds this setting, PHP
; will send that data in chunks of roughly the size you specify.
; Turning on this setting and managing its maximum buffer size can yield some
; interesting side-effects depending on your application and web server.
; You may be able to send headers and cookies after you've already sent output
; through print or echo. You also may see performance benefits if your server is
; emitting less packets due to buffered output versus PHP streaming the output
; as it gets it. On production servers, 4096 bytes is a good setting for performance
; reasons.
; Note: Output buffering can also be controlled via Output Buffering Control
;   functions.
; Possible Values:
;   On = Enabled and buffer is unlimited. (Use with caution)
;   Off = Disabled
;   Integer = Enables the buffer and sets its maximum size in bytes.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to Off for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: 4096
; Production Value: 4096
; http://php.net/output-buffering
output_buffering = 4096
```

The directive `output_buffering` is not the only configurable directive regarding Output buffering. You can find other configurable Output buffering directives here: http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php

**Example: ob_get_clean()**

Below you can see how to capture an `echo` and manipulate it before sending it to the browser.

```
// Turn on output buffering  
ob_start();  

echo 'Hello World';  // save to output buffer

$output = ob_get_clean();  // Get content from the output buffer, and discard the output buffer ...
$output = strtoupper($output); // manipulate the output  

echo $output;  // send to output stream / Browser

// OUTPUT:  
HELLO WORLD
```

**Examples: Hackingwithphp.com**

More info about Output buffer with examples can be found here:

http://www.hackingwithphp.com/13/0/0/output-buffering

Comment: Question, do I need to have display_errors set to On for this buffer to be captured?

Comment: `display_errors` and `output_buffering` are two different things. Correct me if I'm wrong, setting `display_errors` to `"1"` is not necessary.

Answer (score 10):

> The Output Control functions allow you
>   to control when output is sent from
>   the script. This can be useful in
>   several different situations,
>   especially if you need to send headers
>   to the browser after your script has
>   began outputting data. The Output
>   Control functions do not affect
>   headers sent using header()  or
>   setcookie(), only functions such as
>   echo()  and data between blocks of PHP
>   code.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

**More Resources:**

**[Output Buffering With PHP](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Output-Buffering-With-PHP/)**

Answer (score 5):

```
ob_start();  // turns on output buffering
$foo->bar();  // all output goes only to buffer
ob_clean();  // delete the contents of the buffer, but remains buffering active
$foo->render(); // output goes to buffer
ob_flush(); // send buffer output
$none = ob_get_contents();  // buffer content is now an empty string
ob_end_clean();  // turn off output buffering
```

Buffers can be nested, so while one buffer is active, another `ob_start()` activates a new buffer. So `ob_end_flush()` and `ob_flush()` are not really sending the buffer to the output, but to the parent buffer. And only when there is no parent buffer, contents is sent to browser or terminal.

Nicely explained here: https://phpfashion.com/everything-about-output-buffering-in-php

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2019. If you have dedicated server and SSD or better NVM, 3.5GHZ. You shouldn't use buffering to make faster loaded website in 100ms-150ms.

Becouse network is slowly than proccesing script in the 2019 with performance servers (severs,memory,disk) and with turn on APC PHP :) To generated script sometimes need only 70ms another time is only network takes time, from 10ms up to 150ms from located user-server.

so if you want be fast 150ms, buffering make slowl, becouse need extra collection buffer data it make extra cost. 10 years ago when server make 1s script, it was usefull.

Please becareful output_buffering  have limit if you would like using jpg to loading it can flush automate and crash sending.

Cheers.

You can make fast river 
or
You can make safely tama :)

Answer (score -1):

[Output Buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) `ob_start()` function also accept callback function.

You can see the code below. There is a function `callback` that accepts an argument. Here `$buffer` is the string holding content from the `ob_start()` to `ob_end_flush()`.

```
<?php

function callback($buffer)
{
  // it will replace football with cricket
  return (str_replace("football", "cricket", $buffer));
}

ob_start("callback");

?>
<html>
<body>
<p>It like football.</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

The output of the above code is:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>I like cricket.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I also need to explain that output buffering function also works in nested scopes.
example:

```
<?php
    
    ob_start();   
    echo "Hello"; 
        
        ob_start();              // nested ob_start()
        echo "PHP";              
        $v1 = ob_get_contents(); // Stores "PHP" in $v1 variable.
        ob_end_flush();
        
    echo "World"; 
    $v2 = ob_get_contents(); // Stores "Hello PHP World" in $v2 variable.
    ob_end_flush();          

?>
```

Comment: You can't just copy/paste code without given any [reference](https://onlinephp.io/ob-start/examples)