# how to get the result from a php file into a string

Tags: php

example i have a file template.php with:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data['nombre'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($data['values] as $value): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value ?> </td>         
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

and i need the result into a string `$result = get_content_process('template.php',$data);` for use in other process.

```
echo $result;
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Juan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Male</td>         
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brown</td>         
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: could be useful -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering

Comment: Also related: [Modify an Existing PHP Function to Return a String](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8730847/367456)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'template.php';
$result = ob_get_clean()
?>
```

this should do, the $result is the string you need

Comment: if you need to know, it's called output buffering, and it comes very handy when you have to generate and process data in the same script

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you don't flush early, turn implicit flush off.
This function should do the trick:

```
function get_content_process($template, $data) {
   ob_implicit_flush(false);
   include($template);
   $contents = ob_get_contents();
   ob_clean();
   ob_implicit_flush(true);
   return $contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ob_start()` to do something like this

```
<?php
    ob_start( );
    $GLOBALS['data'] = ...;
    include("template.php");
    $result = ob_get_clean();
    echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple and fast solution:

```
$result = file_get_contents($view); // $view == the address of the file(ie 'some_folder/some_file.php')
```