# PHP: emulate the global behavior on an unknown variable inside a function

Tags: php, variables, scope, global-variables

To include raw JavaScript files into my pages, i've ended up using:

```
function include_js($jsfile, $basepath = JSPATH){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    include($basepath . $jsfile);
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Works fine, and the PHP code inside these JS files is still executing fine, no problem here.
But here is some pseudo code of what i used before:

```
<script>
    var hello = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
</script>
```

So, **here's the problem:**

- Before, the PHP code used inside my JavaScript files was executed in the same context as the page's one.
- Now, it's executed in the context of the `include_js()` function.

Thus, i don't have access to any of my page's variables anymore. I could fix it with a `global $id;`, but that was pseudo-code.

Actually, i have NO idea what variables i'll need to have access to.

Any idea how to solve that problem? If you have a better solution than what i'm actually doing inside `include_js()` to achieve the same goal without the problem i'm talking about, that would be as much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could import all global variables (but [Superglobals](http://php.net/Superglobals)) into the local scope of the function where you do the include. I don't think it's really a good solution (as it's a hammer) but as you write in your question you don't know which variables are used, so you could localize them like:

```
$varname = $GLOBALS['varname'];
```

As an alternative you could inspect the JS file and/or provide the list of variables for a file and add it to the include function as an array. See [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7697490/367456) for some code example.

You could also first pre-include (and throw away) the js file, gather the warnings about undefined variables, import them and then include for real. Some [more include/discard/return/variable related chunks of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8730878/367456).

Comment: I'll give my function an array of variables to use. +1 for making me discover the `extract()` function through your first example, which is really awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variables, but a more robust way is to write your own "constant databases". Something like:

```
class ConstantDB{
    public static function set($key, $value){
    }

    public static function get($key){
    }
}
```

It's just very convenient in many cases. For your particular situation, then you can use

```
ConstantDB::set("my_id", $id);
```

and inside the include_js, you can use

```
ConstantDB::get("my_id");
```

Comment: That's a good answer, i already thought about doing that, but i'd rather use something that doesn't require me to re-write a whole bunch of code. I'll accept your answer later if nothing better comes up =)