# Why does PHP send it all at once?

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is output buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering)

I have some content that takes a while to be generated by PHP. Meanwhile I would like to use this simple JS trick to display a "Loading..." message. The message would disappear as soon as the output is generated.

```php
<p id="loading_msg">Loading...</p>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<?php
    sleep(2); // This is the greedy function call
    print '<p>This content definitely took a while to be generated !.</p>';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var e = document.getElementById("loading_msg");
    e.style.display = "none";
</script>
```

The problem is, instead of sending everything up to `sleep(2);` then blocking, it will wait before all the page is generated, and **then**, send it **all at once**. It obviously breaks the purpose of my "Loading..." message, because it doesn't appear before the 2 seconds have elapsed. Any ideas of why, and how I could work around this ?

Comment: Question has beeb closed as a duplicate of one about output_buffering - however this q is about getting content to render in the client before the server has finished (implying the opposite of output buffering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, PHP will buffer your output and send a fewer number of larger chunks to the user. You can use [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) to send the contents of write buffer to the user immediately:

```
<p id="loading_msg">Loading...</p>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<?php
    flush();
    sleep(2);
```

This won't work if you've previously enabled output buffering by calling [`ob_start`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) or the php.ini directive [`output_buffering`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) to `1`.

Comment: I already thought of a buffer problem. Unfortunately, I added `ob_start()` at the first line and `flush()`ed before the `sleep()` and it still behaves the same. (Also tried various combinations with other functions like `ob_flush()` or `ini_set('output_buffering','on')`.)

Comment: Read my answer, it specifically says this doesn't work with `ob_start`. Then read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) which specifically says **"This means you will have to call both `ob_flush()` and `flush()` to flush the ob output buffers"**.

Comment: Got it, I read a little to fast, sorry. It took me a while to understand how `ob_*` functions relate to each other. It indeed works with both `ob_flush(); flush();`. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Using 'flush' might work on some webservers / browsers (meagar is correct that it won't work while output buffering is enabled - but that doesn't mean it will work the rest of the time).

It's up to the webserver to decide when to revert to chunked encoding - most will start a chunked response when you call flush as long as you're not compressing the output stream. Then it's up to the browser to decide when it starts rendering an incomplete response - and behaviour will vary depending on the content too - e.g. none will start rendering a table until it has the closing tag.

A better solution then trying to handle it in the receiving page, is to handle it in the sending page - e.g. using a litebox to display the message. Alternatively the message could be presented in an interim page which does a redirect to the generated content.