# Echo string dynamically in while loop

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is output buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering)
>   [Why does PHP send it all at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544714/why-does-php-send-it-all-at-once)

I want to echo "sent" dynamically when sending emails from list. My script only echos after it finishes all. How can I echo string dynamically in while loop ?

```
$f=fopen("list.txt","r");

if($f){

    while (!feof($f)) {

        $line = fgets($f, 4096);

        $lncount++;

        $val = $lines[$lncount];

        mailsender($line,$yollayan,$sifresi,$name);

        echo "sent";

    }
}
```

Comment: @symcbean: Let's not have duplicates of duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set up the output for buffering. Try the script below. Make sure you switch of zipping of your output to see real time output.

```
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1); 
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$f=fopen("list.txt","r");

if($f){

   while (!feof($f)) {

        $line = fgets($f, 4096);
        $lncount++;
        $val = $lines[$lncount];
        mailsender($line,$yollayan,$sifresi,$name);
        echo " sent";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not worked. Doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  echo "Sent ";
  echo str_repeat("\n",1024);
  flush();
```

From the PHP Manual:

> flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web
>   server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the
>   browser. [...]
>
> Server modules for Apache like mod_gzip may do buffering of their own
>   that will cause flush() to not result in data being sent immediately
>   to the client.
>
> Even the browser may buffer its input before displaying it. Netscape,
>   for example, buffers text until it receives an end-of-line or the
>   beginning of a tag, and it won't render tables until the tag of the
>   outermost table is seen.
>
> Some versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer will only start to
>   display the page after they have received 256 bytes of output, so you
>   may need to send extra whitespace before flushing to get those
>   browsers to display the page.

Comment: Sorry typo mistake ( its flush() not fflush() )

Answer (score 1):

> My script only echos after it finishes all.

It probably does - but you've not provided nearly enough information to determine if this is the case.

Most likely your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544714/why-does-php-send-it-all-at-once).

If you add a flush() after the echo and run it from the command line you'll see the progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flush();` below the echo to send this to the browser: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php (read the comments on the link to get more info).

Answer (score 0):

The effect you're seeing is output buffering.  Call the [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) function to force php to send pending output.

Do read the different caveats and possible limitations that can arise in different scenarios and with different server types.

Comment: I remember I had problems using it on my xampp server.

Comment: @PLB see the php manual page I refer to, it's unfortunately not as simple as just slapping flush() at the end of the loop, there are several platform dependencies and interactions you may have to cope with.