# How to replace displayed output with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to automatically replace an echoed word or phrase in PHP with something predfined?  I tried using `define()`, but that isn't working the way I'd like (or maybe I'm not doing it correctly.

In my database I have all US states but their names are abbreviated as such; MO, AK, AL, IL...

What I'd like to do is create a file that defines MO as Missouri, and IL as Illinois and when MO is echoed, it is automatically replaced with Missouri.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: **str_replace( )** before you echo it ...

Comment: are you comfortable using javascript?

Answer (score 6):

The best way is to buffer the output and then deal with that.

Output buffering is done by calling ob_start() before what you want is about to be echoed. You can then get everything that was echoed using ob_get_clean(), and this takes it out of the buffer queue. You can then do any kind of processing you want on it, and echo it again.

A quick example:

```
<?php
function echoState() { echo "NY"; }

ob_start();
echoState();
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo str_replace("NY","New York",$output);
?>
```

Run it, you will get New York printed on the page.

Comment: `ob_get_clean();` this is the key to write out a object modified later with `str_replace`. I never remember that and im here because i googled for it. Thank you. This technique is widely used to modify the Copyright year on static templates with a default value.

Answer (score 3):

There are several good ways. One is to create a variable that contains your text and then operate on that, rather than echoing the string right away.

Another is to use [output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering), which takes everything you echo and saves it up, allowing you to build your page and then either display it all at once, or dump it into a variable for processing.

Comment: **+1** for mentioning **output buffering**

Answer (score 2):

user `str_replace(find,repalce,from);` function to replace anything in PHP.

Use the below, if you want to replace multiple-pre assigned values:

```
function replacer($searchArray,$replaceArray, $text){

        $searchArray = array("illinois","NewYork","LosAngeles");    
        $replaceArray = array("IL","NY","LA");  

        return str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $text);
        }
```

Now, the replacing part:

`$text =  "this is a full text containing everything you want to be replaced";`

`echo replacer(@$searchArray, @$replaceArray, $text);`