# Refreshing site using unknown url

Tags: php, redirect, refresh

I'm trying to use refresh as a redirect function because header does not work for some reason. Here is piece of my code, when I run it refresh loops:

----------NOT WORKING /---------------

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = substr($url, 10); //cuting url to "index.php?site=page"
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$url.'">';
```

----------WORKING /---------------

```
$url = 'index.php?site=page';
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$url.'">';
```

----------WHOLE FUNCTION /---------------

```
elseif($action=="nfvi") {
        safe_query("UPDATE ".PREFIX."nfv SET nfv=nfv+1");
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = substr($url, 10);
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$url.'">';
}
```

Comment: if your trying to update an integer with +1 then change your query too: `nfv SET nfv='nfv'+1`

Comment: What is the substr for?  what does the original REQUEST_URI look like?

Comment: I want to have: index.php?site=page insted of /~folder/index.php?site=page so thats why I use substr

Answer (score 1):

Why not use HTTP headers?

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.google.com";

header("Location: index.php?site=" . urlencode($url)); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: @shapeshifter Probably. But doesn't seem like OP knows what that means.

Comment: i tried to use: header("Location: index.php?site=".$url.""); - not working

Comment: Read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering  then turn output buffering on, send ur header and see if it works.

Comment: If I can't use double quotes twice so how can I use header with a variable ??? lol

Comment: @qerigan I said before, answer updated. See answer. Why you no read?

Comment: header("Location: index.php?site=".$url);  <- no effect, im still on old page

Comment: what do you mean "your code broke" ? My code is fine i guess, all i have to do is to run function that changes a value in database and refresh the page.

Comment: Try put ob_start(); at the very start of your code.  And try rerun it.

Comment: @qerigan It may be beneficial to future visitors if you told us what your problem was.

Comment: Well it was pretty stupid of me because I didn't noticed that when i called the function url has changed to 'index.php?site=page&action=nfvi' so i changed 'substr($url, 10);' to 'substr($url, 10, -12);'. Anyway I still have problem cuz when its not 'index.php?site=page' but for example 'index.php?site=page3' user is redirected to 'page' insted of 'page3' if you know what I mean ...

Comment: @qerigan just do a string replace, $url = str_replace("/~folder/", "", $url);

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) as initiated as a client:

It will balance CURL_SET TIMEOUT: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);`

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ping_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, trim($request)); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

Are you check for refreshing page in header if header location not working?

```
 header("Refresh: 2;");
```

If header not working, use fsockets for reading a data:

```
$host = 'www.example.com';
$service_uri = '/cgi-bin/processACT';
$vars ='code=22&act=TEST';

$header = "Host: $host\r\n";
$header .= "User-Agent: PHP Script\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($vars)."\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

$fp = pfsockopen("ssl://".$host, 443, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp) {
   echo "$errstr ($errno)<br/>\n";
   echo $fp;
} else {
    fputs($fp, "POST $service_uri  HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fputs($fp, $header.$vars);
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

And than make a loop with `sleep(3)` second with what you want for pause.

Why you are using meta tag instead of header in PHP?

```
header('Location: '.$url);
```

Or full header redirect example:

```
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
```

Comment: What is `cURL` doing here?

Comment: @qerigan Yelling won't help you fix your problem.

Comment: Instead of header you can use CURL or using sockets and refreshing on PHP loop function with sleep or checking. If it is checked than exit from fucntion.

Comment: @qerigan Header redirects work.  You just simply don't understand them.

Comment: maybe I don't understand them but so don't you, because you can't even explain to me how should I use it ...

Comment: @qerigan Yeah pretty hard to explain how to redirect to a url that is wrong.

Comment: Wrong url ? what is wrong with this url: header("Location: index.php?site=page"); ? <- cuz this one gives no effect aswel

Comment: For a start, HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs.  Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I use url "index.php?site=...." in other functions and there it works so your idea wont help