# output_buffering off at run time in php

Tags: php, output-buffering

```
<?php
ini_set('output_buffering','0');
echo 'Begin ...<br />';
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    echo $i . '<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo 'End ...<br />';
?>
```

In the code above I am trying to set `output_buffering` as *off*, but it is not working.

Output is echoing at the end of execution of script.

Comment: Try ob_start (); at the top of your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default output buffering value is set to "0".

- [Runtime Configuration: `output_buffering`](http://www.php.net/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering)
- [Nice Answer to *"What is Output Buffering?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2832179/1484785)

Comment: in my php.ini its set to be 4096, which i cant change

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ob_flush`, just use [`ob_end_flush`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) at the beginning of your script to remove the output buffer.

Also, declare the character encoding of your page, so the browser can show your output right away without having to look at hundreds of input bytes first:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

If your script still does not work, the web server is Apache, and you can create a `.htaccess` file, try doing so with the following contents:

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
```

By the way, the `ini_set` is useless, and you should also include `html`, `head`, and `body` elements. At least for Firefox, including these elements also solves the problem:

```
echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head><body>';
// ...
echo '</body></html>';
```

Comment: nope, still not working :-(