# Merge Two MySQL Queries in one Array

Tags: php, mysql

Purpose of this query is to retrieve a true image plus 3 random generated images from same table, then show them randomly. User(child) have to select correct image.

Thanks

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `user` = '$word'";
" UNION"
"SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `user` != '$word' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";


$row2=mysql_query($sql);

$i=1;
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($row2))
{
 echo '<td> ';
 echo '<img src="sigg/'.$r['img'].'" width="130" height="130" /><br>';
 echo $r['user'];
 echo '</td>';
   $i++;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried something that didn't work?

Comment: I see you significantly updated your question a while ago, but you aren't asking anything anymore. Can you re-read and re-write your question, please? It's a bit confusing now.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\alb\do_search.php on line 22

Comment: @ZAW - There is a mistake in your `$sql=....;` statement. Correct it *(or copy it from my answer)* and the error will be gone.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [**`UNION`** clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
$sql = "(SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `user` = '$word')";
$sql.= " UNION";
$sql.= " (SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `user` != '$word' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)";
$sql.= " ORDER BY RAND()";
```

To get the results you can use for example **[`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** *(poseted before OP added his code with `mysql_*` functions)*:

```
$MySQL=new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
$query = $MySQL -> query($sql);
while ($entry = $query -> fetch_row())
{
    // $entry is an array with the results, use for example:
    echo $entry[0]; // will return the first column of your table
    echo $entry[1]; // will return the second column of your table

    // try also:
    var_dump($entry); // outputs everything for testing purposes
}
```

**Please, don't use the [`mysql_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) functions, they are [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and will be removed in the future versions of PHP. Use [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.** See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/1935077) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not clear enough to provide a solid answer, so I'll try to answer it the best I can.

You should use [Union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) in your query to get one big list of entries. However, just doing

```
SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `user` = '$word'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `user` != '$word' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

will give you a list of entries where `user = $word` in the first part and random 3 other entries.

As I said, I don't know the exact purpose of this, but I think you're better of querying the entire list from your database server.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the php code:

```
$connection = mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME, $connection);

$sql = "SELECT img, user FROM `login` WHERE `user` = '{$word}' UNION SELECT img, user FROM `login` WHERE `user` != '{$word}' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";

$results = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
$rows = array();

// Insert results in a new array to shuffle it
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $rows[] = array(
        'img' => $row['img'],
        'user' => $row['user']
    );
}

shuffle ($rows); // Randomize order

// Construct HTML
$html = '';
foreach ($rows as $entry) {
    $html .= '<td><img width="130px" height="130px" src="sigg/' . $entry['img'] . '">
    $html .= $user . '</img></td>';
}

echo $html;
```

You will need to replace capitalized words with what's necessary.
A few explanations:

- replace `*` with only what you need from tables (use fewer memory)
- first insert results in an array so you can randomize the order (from MySQL you'll always have the first line the results from first query)
- construct the html and output it all at once (executing multiple `echo` relies on the buffering to not send it to the browser, but that option might be off: [What is output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering)).