# How can I add an image inside a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress-shortcode

I have an image displayed in the following manner:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/logo/logo.png">
```

Now, however, I want to create a shortcode that has an attribute and uses that same image inside it. So I tried the following:

```
add_shortcode('scrollTop', function(){
    echo "<a href='#content' class='content'>";
    echo "<img src='bloginfo('"template_directory"')/images/logo/logo.png'">;
    echo "skipping content";
    echo "</a>";
});
```

Its a syntax error I assume, but am struggling to find a way around.

How can I add the image inside the shortcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [concatenation operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) and correct single quotes inside the `bloginfo` function.

```
add_shortcode('scrollTop', function(){
    echo "<a href='#content' class='content'>";
    echo "<img src='" . bloginfo('template_directory') . "/images/logo/logo.png'>";
    echo "skipping content";
    echo "</a>";
});
```

Also make sure to not use `echo` inside your shortcode to display something. Use `return` instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538180/wordpress-using-echo-vs-return-in-shortcode-function) for more information.

```
add_shortcode('scrollTop', function(){
    return "<a href='#content' class='content'>
        <img src='" . bloginfo('template_directory') . "/images/logo/logo.png'>
        skipping content
        </a>";
});
```

Comment: For some reason the image does not show.
First I noticed that the url comes out wrong so I tried to manually adding in the source but the image does not print.
src='https://dev.example/sites/wordpress-staging/05/images/logo/logo.png'

Comment: The shortcode return a broken image as if such does not exist in the directory

Comment: Can you post the url that the img tag is generating?

Comment: I will upvote the question because the answer is correct. The issue am facing has to do with the url configuration. So am now having to the the full staging url in like: https://my.example.com/sites/wp-staging/05/wp-content/themes/themename/images/arrow-up.png