# Method post admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request) error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am trying to develop a custom registration for WordPress users using AJAX by the OOP.

After submitting the form I get this error:

> **POST `http://localhost:10017/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` 400 (Bad Request)**

[image: Screenshot of browser console displaying said 400 bad Request error]

Can anyone help me fix this issue? My WordPress version is 6.1.1.

**Home.php**

```php
<?php
require_once 'inv_setting_page.php';
require_once 'inv_customer_create.php';
require_once 'frontend/inv_user_registration.php';

final class invintegrate {

    const version = '1.0';

    function __construct()    {
        $this->invintegrate_define_constants(); //define asstes
        register_activation_hook( invINTEGARTE_ASSETS_FILE, [ $this, 'invintegrate_assets_activate' ] ); // plugin activation
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'inv_register_assets']);
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', [ $this, 'invintegrate_assets_init_plugin' ] );  // load plugin
    }

    function inv_register_assets() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ChosenJs' , plugins_url('/assets/js/chosen.jquery.min.js' , __FILE__ ) , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'inv-customjs', plugins_url( 'assets/js/custom.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), 0.1, false );
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        wp_localize_script( 'inv-customjs', 'inv_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'userID' => $user_id ) );
    }

    /**
     * Define the required plugin constants
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function invintegrate_define_constants() {
        define( 'invINTEGRATE_ASSETS_VERSION', self::version );
        define( 'invINTEGARTE_ASSETS_FILE', __FILE__ );
        define( 'invINTEGARTE_ASSETS_PATH', __DIR__ );
        define( 'invINTEGARTE_ASSETS_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__  ) );
    }

    public function invintegrate_assets_init_plugin() {
        if (is_admin()) {
            new invSettimngPage();
            new inv_customercreate();
        }else{
            new invuserregistration();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Plugin Activatoin Hook
     */

    public function invintegrate_assets_activate() {

        $installed = get_option( 'invintegrate_installed' );

        if ( ! $installed ) {
            update_option( 'invintegrate_installed', time() );
        }

        update_option( 'invintegrate_assets_version', invINTEGRATE_ASSETS_VERSION );
    }
}


/**   * Create a class instance   */
new  invintegrate();
```

**Registration_form.php** in this file.

**bs_registeration_callback_callback** is the callback function.

```php
<?php
final class invuserregistration{

    function __construct() {
        add_shortcode('inv_user_regsitration_form', [$this, 'inv_user_regsitration']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_bs_registeration_callback', [$this, 'bs_registeration_callback_callback']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_bs_registeration_callback', [$this, 'bs_registeration_callback_callback']);
    }

    function inv_user_regsitration(){

        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            echo '<h6>You have already login</h6>';
        } else { ?>
        <div class="buyer_seller_reg_form">
            <div class="menus_bs">
            <h4>Create your account</h4>
            <!-- <h4><a href="">Login</a></h4>    -->
            </div>
            <form method="POST" name="user_registeration" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label>Username*</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Your Username" id="bs_username" required />
                <br/>
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" id="bs_fullname" required />
                <br/>

                <label>Email address*</label>
                <input type="text" name="useremail" id="bs_email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required />
                <br/>
                <label>Password*</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="bs_password" placeholder="Enter Your password" required />
                <input  type="hidden" pattern="(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|[21][0-9]|0[1-9])" name="dob" placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" id="bs_dob" />
                <br>
                <input type="button" id="bs_registeration" value="SignUp" />
            </form>
            <span id="bs_error_message"></span>
        </div>

        <?php
        }
    }

    function bs_registeration_callback_callback() {
        $bs_username = $_REQUEST['bs_username'];
        $bs_fullname = $_REQUEST['bs_fullname'];          // Rashed Code
        //$bs_phonenumber = $_REQUEST['bs_phonenumber'];   // Rashed Code
        $bs_email    = $_REQUEST['bs_email'];
        $bs_password = $_REQUEST['bs_password'];
        $bs_dob      = $_REQUEST['bs_dob'];
        $bs_address  = $_REQUEST['bs_address'];
        $image_url   = $_FILES['bs_image'];
        $exists      = email_exists($bs_email);
        if ($exists) {
            echo "That E-mail is already Exist";
        }
        else {
            $userdata = array(
                'user_pass'          => $bs_password,
                'user_login'         => $bs_username,
                'user_fullname'      => $bs_fullname,    // Rashed Code
                //'user_phonenumber'   => $bs_phonenumber, // Rashed Code
                'user_nicename'      => $bs_username,
                'user_email'         => $bs_email,
                'role'          => 'subscriber',
            );

            $user_id  = wp_insert_user($userdata);
            if (!is_wp_error($user_id)) {
                //echo "You have registered Successfully";
                echo "Thank you for registering at FREESALE!  Please check your emails to verify your account";
                add_user_meta($user_id, 'fullname', $bs_fullname);
                add_user_meta($user_id, 'phonenumber', $bs_phonenumber);

                //add_user_meta($user_id, 'birthday', $bs_dob);
                //add_user_meta($user_id, 'address', $bs_address);
                add_user_meta($user_id, 'user_earn', '');
                if ($image_url) {
                    $file_name  = $_FILES['bs_image']['name'];
                    $file_temp  = $_FILES['bs_image']['tmp_name'];
                    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                    $image_data = file_get_contents($file_temp);
                    $filename   = basename($file_name);
                    $filetype   = wp_check_filetype($file_name);
                    $filename   = time() . '.' . $filetype['ext'];
                    if (wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path'])) {
                        $file       = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
                    }
                    else {
                        $file       = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
                    }
                    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);
                    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null);
                    $attachment  = array(
                        'post_mime_type'             => $wp_filetype['type'],
                        'post_title'             => sanitize_file_name($filename) ,
                        'post_content'             => '',
                        'post_status'             => 'inherit'
                    );
                    $attach_id   = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file);
                    require_once (ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file);
                    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
                    add_user_meta($user_id, 'image', $attach_id);
                }
            }
            else {
                echo $user_id->get_error_message();
            }
        }
        wp_die();
    }

} /*END the class*/
```

**custom.js**

```js
let ajax_url = inv_ajax_object.ajax_url;
let userId = inv_ajax_object.userID;

jQuery(document).on('click', '#bs_registeration', function () {

    jQuery('#bs_error_message').text('');

    let bs_username = document.getElementById('bs_username').value;
    let bs_fullname = document.getElementById('bs_fullname').value;
    //let bs_phonenumber = document.getElementById('bs_phonenumber').value;
    let bs_email = document.getElementById('bs_email').value;
    let bs_password = document.getElementById('bs_password').value;

    console.log('111');

    if (bs_username === '' || bs_fullname === '' || bs_email === '' || bs_password === '') {
        console.log('222');
        jQuery('#bs_error_message').text('All above Fields are Required');
    } else {
        if (IsEmail(bs_email) == false) {
            jQuery('#bs_error_message').text('email is not valid');
            console.log('333');
        } else {
            jQuery('form').append(`<div class="loader"></div>`);
            jQuery("#bs_registeration").attr("disabled", true);
            // jQuery('#bs_error_message').text('Processing');

            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('action', 'bs_registeration_callback');
            form_data.append('bs_username', bs_username);
            form_data.append('bs_fullname', bs_fullname);
            //form_data.append('bs_phonenumber', bs_phonenumber);
            form_data.append('bs_email', bs_email);
            form_data.append('bs_password', bs_password);

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajax_url,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,
                success: function (response) {
                    //console.log(response == 'Thank you for registering at FREESALE!  Please check your emails to verify your account');
                    jQuery('.loader').remove();

                    if (response == 'Thank you for registering at FREESALE!  Please check your emails to verify your account') {
                    //if (response == 'You have registered Successfully') {

                        jQuery("form").trigger("reset");
                        jQuery('#bs_error_message').text(response);

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            window.location.replace("https://yoga.dizmak.com/login/");
                        }, 100000);

                    } else {
                        jQuery("#bs_registeration").removeAttr("disabled");
                        jQuery('#bs_error_message').text(response);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }
});

function IsEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!regex.test(email)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your jQuery ajax function it's missing action field. You are passing "action: bs_registeration_callback" into form_data instead outside, it should be at the same level like fields 'url' or 'type'. Try to add **action: 'bs_registeration_callback'** as the ajax argument.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            action: 'bs_registeration_callback',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            success: function (response) {
                //console.log(response == 'Thank you for registering at FREESALE!  Please check your emails to verify your account');
                jQuery('.loader').remove();

                if (response == 'Thank you for registering at FREESALE!  Please check your emails to verify your account') {
                //if (response == 'You have registered Successfully') {

                    jQuery("form").trigger("reset");
                    jQuery('#bs_error_message').text(response);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location.replace("https://yoga.dizmak.com/login/");
                    }, 100000);

                } else {
                    jQuery("#bs_registeration").removeAttr("disabled");
                    jQuery('#bs_error_message').text(response);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: while I declare 
add_action('wp_ajax_bs_registeration_callback', [$this, 'bs_registeration_callback_callback']);
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_bs_registeration_callback', [$this, 'bs_registeration_callback_callback']);
    } in OOP. then "Method post admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request) error" is showing. But while I used a procedure that is working properly. Can you tell me how to the proper way used "wp_ajax" in OOP.

Comment: Your add_action's are proper (but not with the best OOP practices). Does debug show any errors while processing ajax call?
Meanwhile, you should fix your shortcode function. The output should be returned, not printed out immediately, otherwise it can be runs twice. More about that you are able to find here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538180/wordpress-using-echo-vs-return-in-shortcode-function)