# How to access a variable from one PHP page to another, without a form, link, or button?

Tags: php, http-post, httprequest, moodle, http-get

**TLDR:-** What is a good way to pass contents of a `variable` from one `PHP file` to another without involving a `form`, `link` or a `button`.

**Question:-**

So there is a `form` in a page/file called `question_edit_form.php` and its `action` attribute is already set to another file called `question.php`. *The variable of interest is being read-in from the user in `question_edit_form.php` and is then obviously being sent to `question.php` using `$_POST`.*

Now, there is a third file, named `renderer.php`, and which is not linked to the other two files. *I want to use that variable of interest in this file.* **So  how can I access that variable which is set in question.php from inside renderer.php?**

Comment: Use session variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the variables in the session.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: never link to w3schools

Comment: @Dagon WHy? Is there something wrong with there tutorials? I do often follow their tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

first file -

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['your_variable'] = 'value';
```

other file -

```
session_start();
$var = $_SESSION['your_variable'];
```

this may help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there are two methods available for you to pass on the value

1. Cookies
2. Sessions

**How to use cookies:-**

```
setcookie(name, value, expire);
```

e.g.

```
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", time()+3600);
```

Access it using `echo $_COOKIE['user'];`

Second is Sessions. **Here is how to use sessions:-**

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['varname']=value;
```

Accessing page:-

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['varname'];
```

**Additional info if required:-**
Make sure you use session_start() at top of your page if not you may face with an headers already sent error / warning which again can be fixed by output buffering `ob_start()`

Comment: I did not get this part: `output buffering ob_start()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering     if you still have doubts after reading it post back

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using Moodle, in which case `renderer.php` is not an independent file; it contains the class definition for the renderer object used by `question.php`.

So... there is no need to pass the parameter between the scripts. If you really must access the form value directly from the renderer, just use the standard methods from the Moodle framework: `required_param($name, $type)` or `optional_param($name,  $default, $type)`.

Comment: That's right I am using Moodle. Thanks for the response, but I actually tried to access it from the renderer by using `required_param('qtype', PARAM_TEXT)`, and also from `attempt.php` (which calls `attempt_page()` function of renderer) but i keep getting `A required parameter $qtype is missing`. The network monitor in Firefox also shows that it is not being received by `renderer.php` or `attempt.php`, while it does get sent from the original form.

Comment: The worse part is that the session variables are not working for me either.

Comment: @Zarah How are you using `renderer.php`? It's usually included within a script (via `$PAGE->get_renderer()`), not accessed directly from the browser.

Comment: Yes, the renderer of interest is the renderer of the `Quiz` module. In attempt.php of quiz module, we get the renderer instance by `$PAGE->get_renderer('mod_quiz');` and then use that renderer instance to call the method `attempt_page()`... Now, the variable I need to use in this `attempt_page()` method is read in from the user in the `edit_question_form.php` (in the `Question plugin`); the `action` of this form is set to `question.php`, so the variable is being sent to  `question.php`. Now I need to access this variable from `question.php` from the Quiz renderer.