# Need to get dynamic HTML content as a string

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I want to be able too add this piece of code in a  surrounded by an echo""

and stil be able to output the variables that is currently in the  like below. This is where my mind is shutting down badly.

```
  <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['leaveID']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
  <td><a href='Leavedetail.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['leaveID']; ?>'> <?php echo $row_Recordset1['serviceNumber']; ?>&nbsp; </a></td>
  <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['rank']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
  <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['organisation']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
  <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['lastName']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
  <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['firstName']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
  <td><a class='btn btn-default' href='userDeleteProcess.php?id={$row_Recordset1['leaveID']}'>Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's best if your question title says something about the problem you're trying to solve.. That way the next person with a similar problem will be able to benefit from your question and any answers. Please consider editing your question to clarify the title.

Comment: I would suggest using an heredoc - You can read about it in the PHP [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question.

Comment: DavidG, what do you mean by vandalising my own question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in need of using `ob_get_contents();`

> Your code will look like this.

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['leaveID']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
      <td><a href='Leavedetail.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['leaveID']; ?>'> <?php echo $row_Recordset1['serviceNumber']; ?>&nbsp; </a></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['rank']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['organisation']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['lastName']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['firstName']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
      <td><a class='btn btn-default' href='userDeleteProcess.php?id={$row_Recordset1['leaveID']}'>Delete</a></td>

<?php
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [cases](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) if you cannot use [`output buffering`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering) as *@PratikSoni* suggested, I would recommend looking up [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) or [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) functions for having formatted output.

Usage example:

```
$output .= sprintf("<td>%s&nbsp;</td>", $row_Recordset1['leaveID']);
```

This way you have it in a variable, and could do `echo` or whatever else you might need it for.

Answer (score -1):

See if this works

```
<td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['leaveID']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
<td><a href='Leavedetail.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['leaveID']; ?>'> <?php echo $row_Recordset1['serviceNumber']; ?>&nbsp; </a></td>
<td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['rank']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
<td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['organisation']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
<td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['lastName']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
<td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['firstName']; ?>&nbsp; </td>
<td><a class='btn btn-default' href='userDeleteProcess.php?id={$row_Recordset1['leaveID']}'>Delete</a></td>
```