# php need to direct user to another page after succesfull completion of a task

Tags: php, forms

I have a token page i need the user to upload an image and when done not able to go back but when I put my direction page for after completion lamp won't upload or complete the task but if i remove the page it complete fine any help from the logic applied here is the code the problem is where the bold line in code is that redirection`

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
    header ("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$jobnumber="try_";
$random_digit=rand(0000,9999).$jobnumber;

//combine random digit to you file name to create new file name
//use dot (.) to combile these two variables

$new_file_name=$random_digit. basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir .$new_file_name;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    require_once("mysql_connect.php"); 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO imagepath (jobnumber,imagepath)
VALUES ('$_POST[Name]','$target_file')";

 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        **header("location:logout.php");**
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }

}

?>`
```

Comment: One solution is `output buffering` which helps with redirect headers. Here's a link with info if you don't get a different suitable answer. [Output Buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do a `header` if you've output anything to the browser.  So here:

```
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
    header ("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
```

There's no need for your `?> <?php` (it just sends a line break to the browser, ruining your `header` options) so remove those lines. Then, a rough solution would be to, anywhere you `echo` a result, instead, put it in the `$_SESSION`, such as:

```
$_SESSION['upload_error'] = 'File is not an image.';
```

Then, you would want to modify your logic so that if `$uploadOk == 0` you redirect them back to the upload page, and on *that* page, if `$_SESSION['upload_error']` is not empty, display it. Otherwise, redirect them elsewhere. If you need help with that particular logic, let me know.

---

A crude and quick solution with minimal-ish changes for time's sake. There are definitely some optimizations you could do, but this should work for your needs.

Let's say the image handling file is `upload.php`, and your form is displayed on something else, like, `index.php`

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
        header ("Location: index.php");
    }

    $_SESSION['upload_error'] = null;
    $_SESSION['upload_success'] = null;

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $jobnumber="try_";
    $random_digit=rand(0000,9999).$jobnumber;

    //combine random digit to you file name to create new file name
    //use dot (.) to combile these two variables

    $new_file_name=$random_digit . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $target_file = $target_dir . $new_file_name;
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if ($check === false) {
            $_SESSION['upload_error'] =  "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $_SESSION['upload_error'] = "File already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000) {
        $_SESSION['upload_error'] = "Your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Allow certain file formats
    if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        $_SESSION['upload_error'] = "Only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if ($uploadOk == 1) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $_SESSION['upload_success'] = "The file " . basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            $uploadOk = 0;  
        }
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 1) {
        # This is where I make an obligatory comment about how you should not use user-provided data ($_POST['Name']) directly in a query, 
        # which is 100% true, but is a topic for another question
        require_once("mysql_connect.php"); 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO imagepath (jobnumber, imagepath) VALUES ('" . $_POST['Name'] . "', '$target_file')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

        header("Location: success.php");
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php"); // send them back to the form, where you will display your error message
    }

?>
```

And this would be the very bare skeleton of `index.php`:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    # This will vary a lot depending on if you're in an MVC setup and/or using a templating engine, etc, but basically:

    // display HTML things like a header, etc

    if (!empty($_SESSION['upload_error'])) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded: " . $_SESSION['upload_error'];
    }

    // display the rest of your HTML

?>
```

`success.php` would be similar, but obviously you'd display a success message; you could do this on `index.php` instead, checking in that file that `!empty($_SESSION['upload_success'])` and displaying it if it's not.

Comment: Thanks Davis the actual logic will be great direction  thanks in advance

Comment: @Tim, check my edit for specifics. Please be sure to accept the answer if it works for you. Let me know if you have any problems.