# echo out value on top of another value

Tags: php

I think it would be simple but I seem not to get it done. what I want to do is to display value I get from FOREACH loop on top of other echoed values.

```
function writeMsg($total) {
echo $total. "< This must display First";
}

foreach ($array as $value) {
   echo $value["Price"]."<br>";
   $total = $value["Total"];
}

writeMsg($total);
```

Note that I already echo the value inside the foreach, but what I want is to echo the variable I got from

```
$total = $value["Total"];
```

before

```
 echo $value["Price"]."<br>";
```

I hope you guys understand my issue!

Comment: you echo in the foreach. if you dont want that to appear that output before the other output, dont echo in the foreach.

Comment: No, your question is not clear.

Comment: so you want to echo the $total right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering):

```
ob_start(); // everything echo'ed now is buffered
foreach ($array as $value){
    echo $value["Price"]."<br>";
    $total = $value["Total"];
}
$all_the_echoes = ob_get_clean(); // capture buffer to variable

writeMsg($total); // echoes the total
echo $all_the_echoes; // echoes the captured buffer
```

Note that there is probably a cleaner solution, but unless you update your question, it's guesswork to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks buddy, this is exactly what i  was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i am not completely sure what are trying to get, but my guess is:

```
function writeMsg($total) {
echo $total. "< This must display First";
}
$total = 0;
$prices = array();

foreach ($array as $value){
    $prices [] = $value["Price"];
    $total += $value["Total"];
}

echo implode("<br>", $prices);
echo "<br>";
writeMsg($total);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want looks something like this. In the foreach loop you want to accumulate data and echo them out later. there you can choose what to echo first.

```
function writeMsg($total) {
    echo $total. "< This must display First";
}


$total = 0;
$prices = '';

foreach ($array as $value){
    // concatenate all prices into a single string. echo this later (after echo of totals)
    $prices .= $value["Price"]."<br>";

    // sum up total of all values
    $total += $value["Total"];
}

writeMsg($total);
echo $prices;
```