# How to replace entire numbers in a website to persian numbers via PHP?

Tags: php

How to replace entire numbers in body or website html to persian numbers via PHP?
I want to replace all numbers in my website for all pages .

**Code:**

```
function ta_persian_num($string) {
  //arrays of persian and latin numbers
  $persian_num = array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹');
  $latin_num = range(0, 9);

  $string = str_replace($latin_num, $persian_num, $string);

  return $string;
}
```

My Code work for Client Side:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    persian={0:'۰',1:'۱',2:'۲',3:'۳',4:'۴',5:'۵',6:'۶',7:'۷',8:'۸',9:'۹'};
    function traverse(el){
        if(el.nodeType==3){
            var list=el.data.match(/[0-9]/g);
            if(list!=null && list.length!=0){
                for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
                    el.data=el.data.replace(list[i],persian[list[i]]);
            }
        }
        for(var i=0;i<el.childNodes.length;i++){
            traverse(el.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
    traverse(document.body);
});
</script>
```

Comment: So, what's the problem with provided code?

Comment: I'm new with PHP how should I use this function for all body numbers,I mean how to replace entire numbers in body automaticaly

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei what do you mean by body?! this function is so simple, just pass you string as a parameter, and it will replace the numbers and then return the string!

Comment: I want replace all numbers in my website, all pages

Comment: Does your website use PHP?

Comment: yes php website with many php pages

Comment: Use javascript instead

Comment: Is there any server side way? for replacing all numbers with a short code in server?

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei It depends on the source of your "body" strings. If they are from multiple sources, you have a lot of work to do in php, so it's better to use something client-side.

Comment: Thanks But I have Client side Solution, I need an example for server side.

Comment: Maybe [output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering) help you. Using it, you can get all printed content in variable and run your function on it.

Comment: PHP doesn't know a `<body>` tag. It just generates text and sends it to the client.

Comment: Is bettter to do that with css or js? what should I do with this question? :D

Comment: I think everybody told you already. Use JS. (Don't know what you wanna do with CSS though)

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei Do you use any PHP frameworks for a website?

Comment: No, Just PHP, index.php and many pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

✅ Solved My Problem with This way:

1: Use FontCreator 9 or 10 Program.
2: Open your font in FontCreator.
3: Goto Numbers tab.
4: Paste your RTL language numbers (Persian/Hebrew/Arabic) On english numbers.

Enjoy Without any F... Functions / Extra Processing.

Photo:
[image: Photo]

Update:
It should also be replaced on Arabic too

Final View Photo
[image: Photo2]

Comment: Odd, but interesting solution. Please note that users who cannot download this font will get arabic numbers displayed.

Comment: @Lithilion Yes that's right, It should also be replaced on Arabic too, I updated the answer with a new Photo.

Comment: No, thats not the point. If someone cannot load your custom font, there is a fallback to a system font (i.e. Arial, Times New Roman,...) and these will have the "standart" numbers on these places

Comment: Yes True But This Solution works 99% for all users if you use all font formats(eot.woff.woff2 and ...),

Answer (score 4):

You should better move this functionality to frontend end use javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var replaceDigits = function() {
    var map = ["&\#1776;","&\#1777;","&\#1778;","&\#1779;","&\#1780;", "&\#1781;","&\#1782;","&\#1783;","&\#1784;","&\#1785;"]
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\d(?=[^<>]*(<|$))/g, function($0) { return map[$0]});
}
window.onload = replaceDigits;
</script>
```

Ex: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rQWGRd

or you can include this function in any your js file which is loaded on all pages.

And also your body tag should have a onload attribute like the following:

```
<body onload="replaceDigits()">
```

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei So what happened to "Thanks But I have Client side Solution, I need an example for server side"?  You were advised to use Javascript almost 30 minutes ago and you refused.  What changed?

Answer (score 3):

The nicest way to do in PHP, is using regular expressions:

```
$string='salam 1 23 12';
$persian_num = array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹');
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $string = preg_replace("/$i/", $persian_num[$i], $string);
}
print($string);
```

Code above, replaces all English numbers with your specified characters in Persian.

Comment: isnt safer use mb_ereg_replace instead preg_replace?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this in PHP, you can concat all text/html output into the same variable and then `echo` it in the end. Between the the last concat and the `echo` you can call this function, in every .php page you echo output.

```
<?php
//Code...
$string = ta_persian_num($string);
echo $string;
```

Personally I would prefer JS for this question.

Comment: How to pass my page numbers from $string  ? Can you write an example for index.php ?   I mean something like this :    ta_persian_num(document.body)

Comment: That's the thing. There is no `document.body` in PHP. You have to write all the output into `$string`or whatever you call it and then call this funtion.

Comment: This is not a good solution because I can't write all of my output into $string