# How can I convert Persian/Arabic digits from the string to English digits?

Tags: php

I have a website in Persian. The keyboard of my website's users is in Persian *(or Arabic)* usually. So their password will not get matched sometimes.

I have a function for their username *(cell-phone number)* which converts Persian/Arabic digits to English:

```
function convert_digits_to_en($entry){
    $fmt = numfmt_create('fa', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
    return numfmt_parse($fmt, $entry);
}
```

It will work **if the entry contains all digits.**

i.e. `۰۹۱۲۳۵۶۵۴۹۸` will be converted to `09123565498` as well.

---

The problem is when the entry contains both characters and digits *(like a password)*. i.e. `test۰۹۱۲`. I need to convert it to `test0912`. My current function returns an [empty string](https://3v4l.org/H5EMY) for that entry. Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: I just had a déjà vu, I've definitely seen this / similar question asked today and it was suggested to use client side and not PHP. **Edit:** Turns out it was something else, similar but not same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264154/how-to-replace-entire-numbers-in-a-website-to-persian-numbers-via-php/53322340#53322340

Comment: regex is probably best suited for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert Persian/Arabic numbers to English numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766726/convert-persian-arabic-numbers-to-english-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex solution would be this:

```
function convert_digits_to_en($input)
{
  $arabic = ['۰' => 0, '۱' => 1];

  return strtr($input, $arabic);
}

echo convert_digits_to_en('test۱۰۰'); // test100
```

**Note:** You'd need to add in the numbers to that array, my Persian / Arabic is not that good.

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/IroncladSmoothAutoresponder)

**Reading Material**

[`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot for validating Persian phone numbers with Persian characters like ۱۲۳۴ using regex in Laravel but found no suitable answer so instead of validating Persian number I decided to change Persian numbers to English and validate it myself, it helped me a lot, hope this helps:

```
if (is_numeric($mobile) && strlen($mobile) == 11) {
      // if number in english
}else{
    $mobile = str_split($mobile , 2);
    if (count($mobile) != 11) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors('فرمت شماره موبایل باید عدد و ۱۱ رقم باشد');
    }
    foreach ($mobile as $key => $number) {
        if ($number == '۰') {
            $mobile[$key] = 0;
        }elseif ($number == '۱') {
            $mobile[$key] = 1;
        }elseif ($number == '۲') {
            $mobile[$key] = 2;
        }elseif ($number == '۳') {
            $mobile[$key] = 3;
        }elseif ($number == '۴') {
            $mobile[$key] = 4;
        }elseif ($number == '۵') {
            $mobile[$key] = 5;
        }elseif ($number == '۶') {
            $mobile[$key] = 6;
        }elseif ($number == '۷') {
            $mobile[$key] = 7;
        }elseif ($number == '۸') {
            $mobile[$key] = 8;
        }elseif ($number == '۹') {
            $mobile[$key] = 9;
        }
    }
    $mobile = implode($mobile);
    if(is_numeric($mobile) == false){
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors('فرمت شماره موبایل باید عدد و ۱۱ رقم باشد');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a short and fast solution, I suggest try this:

```
function fa2en($str) {
    return strtr($str, array('۰'=>'0', '۱'=>'1', '۲'=>'2', '۳'=>'3', '۴'=>'4', '۵'=>'5', '۶'=>'6', '۷'=>'7', '۸'=>'8', '۹'=>'9'));
}
```

Comment: You should have edited [Script47's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53323027/3789665).

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: @greybeard Suggested edit queue is full.