# get resulting content of a file without including it

Tags: php

01.php

```
<div class='title'>title</div>
```

02.php

```
<?php include('01.php');?>
```

some function:

```
$a = file_get_contents('02.php');
echo $a;
```

Result:

```
<?php include('01.php');?>
```

Is there a way to refer `02.php` (**without** including it in the current file) and get this:

```
<div class='title'>title</div>
```

This is a simplified example. In reality `02.php` is a large file with `01.php` included somewhere inside.

Comment: Why can't you just use the `include()`? I'm not sure I understand that. Regardless, if that is not an option, you need to look into using the output buffer along with `file_get_contents`.

Comment: @JeremyHarris, pls an example of `output buffer`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering

Comment: Not always an option or a good option, but `$a = file_get_contents('http://example.com/02.php');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse the php file and save the result to a variable instead of outputting it you could use:

```
ob_start();
include("01.php");
$a = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

You will have the parsed php in $a but it will not be output to the user. 
More info: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php