# What is the difference between values 1 and 4096 of output_buffering in php.ini

Tags: php, output-buffering

What does exactly the value of `output_buffering` ini variable mean in php.ini?
On our older server, it was set to 1

```
output_buffering = 1
```

> With this setting, I could call `ob_clean();` and it worked like a
>   charm. However, we moved our system to a new server where the output
>   buffering was set to 4096:

```
output_buffering = 4096
```

With this, calling `ob_clean();` did not have any effect, until I explicitly started the very beginning of my code with `ob_start();` (It seems that on the other server with output_buffering=1 it was called implicitly).

Comment: `4096` is size of output that is buffered by default.

Comment: PD of [What is output buffering?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2832010)

Comment: Your `php.ini`, the PHP Manual and the tag name `Output buffering` you added to your question will all supply you with lot's of information about Output buffering.

Comment: @Peter Okay maybe the title is misleading, but please read the question: you can see I was not actually asking what output buffering is, but why is the value 1 explicitly starts output buffering at the beginning of my script but with the value of 4096 I have to explicitly call ob_start();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is output buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering)

Comment: @Dave Please read the question

Comment: @mario please read the question

Comment: @ACs Please read the link, and the manual section contained therein.

Comment: There is at least one answer in the duplicate link that explains things very clearly.

Comment: That is so easy to google, dear ACs. = 1 means simply 'On' with the default of the current version. 4096 is 'On' with a concrete value: http://php.net/manual/de/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **output_buffering** *boolean/integer*
>
> You can enable output buffering for all files by setting this directive to 'On'. If you wish to limit the size of the buffer to a certain size - you can use a maximum number of bytes instead of 'On', as a value for this directive (e.g., output_buffering=4096). This directive is always Off in PHP-CLI.

From [the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering)

What this means is :

- A value of `0` is false/off so output buffering is disabled.
- A value of `1` is true/on so that output buffering is enabled and has no set limit (at least in this scope) to the maxmum buffer size.
- A value of  `>1` is the maximum number of bytes for a custom output buffer size.

Therefore, choices above in the PHP.ini config are:

> ```
>     output_buffering= 0 / 1 / 1+
> ```