# Wordpress Plugin, get HTML page or post content as a string

Tags: php, wordpress, dom, plugins

I am building a word press plugin and I need to get back the page and post content as an html string. I want it back as a string so that I can search the DOM for particular elements with a tag and then do something with those elements when found.

The problem is when I use

```
the_content();
```

or

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $the_content());
```

It seems to always display (render) the content on my plugin page which is not what I want. I just want the output back as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong

```
$the_content()
```

To be honest I am not sure how that works with a `$`, but any call to `the_content()` will just output it.

You can use

> get_the_content( string $more_link_text = null, bool $strip_teaser = false )
>
> Retrieve the post content [as a string]

In any case you can always use output buffering, if no other way exists

```
ob_start();
the_content();
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

you can see this answer about what Output buffering is.

[What is output buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering)

Basically when you output "stuff" it goes into a buffer, normally you have no control over this and it eventually gets dumped into the response.  With output buffering you can capture that "stuff" into a buffer you can control.

Obviously it's preferable to use a method that returns a string directly, I just thought I would share the Output buffering "method" in case you need that ability for something that does not provide such a method.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, I am quite new to both word press and php you seemed to understand what I was asking anyway, cheers!

Comment: I been doing PHP for over a decade and I manage around 6 wordpress sites for our company ... lol ... That said they don't let me do much design work anymore. My PHP skillz are too valuable...  For example I just created a Rest API over the last 2 weeks, using RabbitMq and Sphinx search engine... :-)  I'm actually taking a break from documenting it.  (yes it's after hours... I have many projects to do)