# php readfile() prints file contents

Tags: php, printing, echo, readfile

I have written a the beginning of a class and there is already a weird problem:

````
<?php
include('class-Park.php');
class park_searcher {```

    public function __construct() {
        // read json file and create each 'Park'
        $this->readjson();
    }

    public function print_parks() {
        // print every park as a json array that the javascript can use
    }
   
    // read json file and create each 'Park'
    public function readjson() {
        // read json file and create each 'Park' and add the complete object to an array of every park

        // why is readfile() printing the contents of the file?
        $raw = readfile("library/parks.txt");

    }

}
````

Instead of `readfile()` just setting `$raw` to the value of the file, the browser is echoing the contents of the file onto the page.  Why is the `readfile()` function acting like `echo` and printing out the file contents?

Comment: The manual for `readfile()` says *Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.*!

Comment: `Why is the readfile() function acting like echo`... because that's its job.

Comment: @NigelRen yes but the output buffer stays hidden unless the computer is told to print it to the page which there is no command to do.

Comment: @ADyson are you saying that I should use a different function to keep the file contents hidden?

Comment: `the output buffer stays hidden unless the computer is told to print it`... Where did you read that? Not sure you've got accurate info there. That isn't the default behaviour. Anyway to read the file into a string you need https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php. read the duplicate question in the blue box above your question - it already shows you what to do.

Comment: [What is output buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering)