# Apache2 - Segmentation fault

Tags: php, apache

the Apache server generate to /var/log/apache2/error.log:

*[Tue Oct 16 11:36:40 2012] [notice] child pid 4091 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)*

I run PHP application with MySQL database. Other application are OK.

The problem is PHP code or server?

Edit, parameter system:

- OS Ubuntu 12.04
- Apache/2.2.22
- PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-3580-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-l

Comment: The problem was PHP code. (Helped step commenting dependency.)