# Trouble on localhost: Must update page many times

Tags: performance, xampp, localhost, updates

I'm currently making a webpage and running it locally on localhost for testing. But whenever I make a change to that page and want to see the result in the browser I run into a "problem". I have to update (press F5 or the update button in the browser) several times for the site to show. In the meantime it's just white...
Let's say I have the site up in my browser (looking good), and then I make a change and want to see it. I press the update button in my browser one time and the site is now just white. I press it again and again, but it stays white. Until I press it a random number of times, and it works. Sometimes I just have to update once, and sometimes I have to update 7-8 times. Sometimes it's fast as hell, and other times it's slow as my schools computers.

Does anyone know if there might be a problem with the site itself (and this problem will continue to exist, even after I upload it to the server), or if it's just a problem with my internet/ computer/ known problem when running on localhost?

I'm using XAMPP on a Mac and have tried testing the page in both Safari and Chrome.

Thanks for all the tips in advance!

From Europe with a problem,
Alekplay

**EDIT 1:**
It turns out Chrome decided to give me an error message instead of a white screen now. It says "no data received", and Safari is still just blank. Any ideas? I've tried turning off caching.

**EDIT 2:**
Did some tweaking here and there, and found out that it's SimpePies autoloader.php that's causing my problems. Any of you have any knowledge around SimplePie, and know how I can make the site load faster? It's fine when I've commented out `require_once('php/autoloader.php');`, but I need that for my feeds to load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Into chrome you can turn caching off. Just take a look to this page :

http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2011/09/disable-google-chrome-cache/

Comment: Please se my reply to the other answer. It's about the same thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome: CTRL+SHIFT+R
I don't know about Safari.
That may be something related with the cache or with apache itself.

Comment: Okay, thanks for answering my question, but sadly it didn't solve the problem. I tried to turn off caching, but it's still slow and needs to be updated a lot (for future reference, turning off cache in Safari is just pressing "developer" and then "deactivate caching" (or something, mine is in norwegian)).

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I would love to show you some code, but I don't know what to show you. I have several documents, with hundreds of lines with code... I can't start uploading everything. I just wondered whether you guys knew if this was a "normal" issue or not?

Comment: Ok. Try with a simple HTML file, no javascript or complex CSS. And check the difference. Apache or browser may be working fine, and it's something with the code.

Comment: Okay, so I've tried with some other local sites and they seem to work fine. Do you have any idea of what might be causing this (connection to database, php code, javascript, jquery, css etc)?

Comment: Well, I tried removing some stuff that I thought was the problem, and found out that it's Simplepies autoloader.php.
Do you have any knowledge of Simplepie? Do you know how I can make the site run faster and without problems?

Answer (score 0):

Find out if you have any error on apache's error.log. It might be related to an error similar to this one:

> AH00052: child pid 62969 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

then you should check: ["[notice] child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" in apache error.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo)

Basically it states to try to increase output_buffering in your php.ini

You would have to run a backtrace on the coredump to know why it crashed, as indicated elsewhere. In mi case it was APC, and the error went away as soon as it was disabled on php.ini. Yours might be because some other cause.