# centos Apache "Child pid *** exit signal Segmentation fault (11)” in error_log

Tags: php, python, apache, gdb, centos

i'm getting a lot "Child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" in my apache log file
I tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo) to find the error in no avail.

Please help me understand this error it has something to do with python 2.4

Edit: I just want to point out that the website generating this error is totally in php.

Here is the result of gdb:

```
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
PyErr_Restore (type=0x2b8ef0870aa0, value=0x2b8ee5d92d40, traceback=0x0) at Python/errors.c:39
39      Python/errors.c: No such file or directory.
        in Python/errors.c
(gdb) backtrace full
#0  PyErr_Restore (type=0x2b8ef0870aa0, value=0x2b8ee5d92d40, traceback=0x0) at Python/errors.c:39
        tstate = 0x0
        oldtype = <value optimized out>
        oldvalue = <value optimized out>
        oldtraceback = <value optimized out>
#1  0x00002b8ef05b9537 in PyErr_SetString (exception=0x2b8ef0870aa0, string=<value optimized out>) at Python/errors.c:70
        value = 0x2b8ee5d92d40
#2  0x00002b8ef05c91b3 in PyModule_AddObject (m=0x2b8efb47ac20, name=0x2b8ef4b25890 "accept2dyear", o=0x2b8efba963d8)
    at Python/modsupport.c:598
        dict = <value optimized out>
#3  0x00002b8ef05c9227 in PyModule_AddIntConstant (m=0x2b8efb47ac20, name=0x2b8ef4b25890 "accept2dyear", value=<value optimized out>)
    at Python/modsupport.c:628
        o = 0x2b8efba963d8
#4  0x00002b8ef4b25767 in inittime () from /usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload/timemodule.so
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00002b8ef269a02d in _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00002b8ef269853d in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00002b8ef2698a5b in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00002b8ef2698bc7 in PyImport_ImportModuleEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#9  0x00002b8ef26793a3 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x00002b8ef26217e0 in PyObject_Call () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x00002b8ef267c32d in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#12 0x00002b8ef267e00a in PyEval_EvalFrame () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#13 0x00002b8ef26826d5 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#14 0x00002b8ef2682722 in PyEval_EvalCode () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#15 0x00002b8ef269702a in PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#16 0x00002b8ef269756c in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#17 0x00002b8ef269853d in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#18 0x00002b8ef26989bc in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#19 0x00002b8ef2698c01 in PyImport_ImportModuleEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#20 0x00002b8ef26793a3 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
No symbol table info available.
#21 0x00002b8ef26217e0 in PyObject_Call () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#22 0x00002b8ef2622433 in PyObject_CallFunction () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#23 0x00002b8ef2698fd8 in PyImport_Import () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#24 0x00002b8ef2699185 in PyImport_ImportModule () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
No symbol table info available.
#25 0x00002b8ef23d3b71 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_python.so
No symbol table info available.
#26 0x00002b8ef23d403d in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_python.so
No symbol table info available.
#27 0x00002b8ee72e869d in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#28 0x00002b8ee72e8cce in apr_pool_destroy () from /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#29 0x00002b8ee5a2bf0e in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#30 0x00002b8ee5a2c3bb in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#31 0x00002b8ee5a2c57a in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
#32 0x00002b8ee5a2cddd in ap_mpm_run ()
No symbol table info available.
#33 0x00002b8ee5a06fd8 in main ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I found the solution to my issue it was because of the Python module. I removed it and the issue is gone.

I don't know if it's an old version or something but anyways it's solved now,

Answer (score 0):

My server team fixed this issue by recompiling Apache

SSH
/scripts/easyapache

And it work.

Before that, my site was blank

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your PHP-FPM and PHP versions match. Make sure there is a (correct) PHP-FPM configuration corresponding to your PHP and PHP-FPM version, respectively.

PHP-FPM (config in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm`) and PHP versions may have gotten out of sync while updating. Updated PHP (`/etc/php/7.3/`) may cause apache child segfaults because of missing PHP-FPM configuration in `/etc/php/7.3/`.

See also [“[notice] child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)” in apache error.log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54841259/10050838) .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22290775)

Comment: @Selaron Yes, this is the essence of that given link's answer.