# localhost padding, signal segmentation fault

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu

im using Ubuntu 12.04 and recently my localhost started not working when trying to access my wordpress files. `http://localhost` itself works and shows the default page, however `http://localhost/wordpress` doesnt. instead it shows me this error : `Firefox can't find the server at www.localhost.com`.

then it shows me that error reporting screen in ubuntu to submit a report, but then it says error the report couldnt be submitted because of padding.

now, when i check my apache logs, i get this : `[Sat Sep 07 14:02:21 2013] [notice] child pid 16225 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2`

i have no idea how to fix this or what i did wrong or if its just a bug. it started not working a few days ago. my system is updated but still the issue persists. i've only been using Ubuntu for a few months so i dont understand that segamentation fault its talking about.

how can i resolve this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and changed `LogLevel warn` to `LogLevel debug` in the apache config. On restart it seemed to be segfaulting just after mod_deflate.

Turning off mod_deflate in debian/ubuntu should just be `sudo a2dismod deflate`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following article. I don't know if it will help but it's worth a try.
According to the author, the problem is that your system core file size is set to 0.
http://sysadmin.carlusgg.com/?p=197

That top part seems to be half the solution. The rest of the solution is to create a folder for Core Dumps and add the directory to httpd.conf

Follow this tutorial:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configure-apache-web-server-for-core-dump.html

Edit: None of the above solutions have solved it for me, actually. Maybe it will work for you.

I recently tried changing the owner of the /etc/apache2 folder to www-data. It's lessened the number of signal segmentation faults, but hasn't solved it.

*Edit from 2020: The above (changing the /etc/apache2 folder owner to www-data) is not a good idea in practice.*

Have you tried using gdb to trace the problem. See the following thread:
["[notice] child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" in apache error.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo)

Edit: I placed Nginx in front of Apache and I am no longer receiving segmentation faults in the Apache error log. I also think the configuration is a better implementation then Apache  on its own. I know it's not a direct solution to the problem but if the segmentation faults are difficult to trace and causing problems, it may be worth implementing this solution.