# "no data received" from local site in Apache?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

Basically I have setup local site, and pointed a `TLD` to that location for development purposes. But now I have a problem, because **I can only load the website exactly once**, subsequent attempts to access the site gets a `no data received` page in Chrome. And the following error gets logged:

```
[Fri Nov 01 11:23:33 2013] [notice] child pid 4988 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

I then restart apache, and can load the website again for one time. And if I reload it, I am back to situation mentioned above... Any ideas?

PS. It is exact same situation regardless of I try to access it using the `TLD` or `localhost` address.

EDIT:

Ok I have examined the crash using the `gdb`, so it appears to do something with `libc.so.6`.. here is the backtrace:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007f72c113b94a in waitpid () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000441c84 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000442d0c in wait_for ()
#3  0x0000000000434684 in execute_command_internal ()
#4  0x000000000043618e in execute_command ()
#5  0x000000000041e3ed in reader_loop ()
#6  0x000000000041c906 in main ()
```

Any ideas what in PHP/Codeigiter uses this library? What could I disable?

Comment: I think you need to provide more data. Like what does your site do? Running some kind of framework(PHP, Python, etc)? What modules do you use? Maybe show your host configuration that is used. Maybe this is of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo?rq=1

Comment: I use Codeigniter.. And actually I have deleted the index.php file, so  php does not get executed. And it actually started working, normally.So this is either PHP or CodeIgniter problem.. any Ideas?

Comment: One of the answers in the question you linked suggests to disable all non essential modules... what are the non esential ones?

Comment: Does this problem only occur when printing codeigniter page or with any PHP?

Comment: I solved. The code I downloaded was using assigning by reference in one place.. and it was giving me error, saying it was deprecated. As soon as I removed that bit of code, it started working as usual :)

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept (after some time), for future references. :-)