# Apache server var/www becoming unavailable after 5 minutes

Tags: apache

I have some php files under var/www directory on my Apache server. When I restart the server I can access them for something like 5 minutes and after they are not available anymore. The page tries to load but nothing happens (some kind of infinite loading) and I have to restart the server again.

**Edit :**
As requested here is the log :

```
[Mon Dec 02 16:13:40 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.6-2ubuntu4.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8g mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 02 16:16:30 2013] [notice] child pid 1387 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Dec 02 16:16:31 2013] [notice] child pid 1388 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Dec 02 16:16:31 2013] [notice] child pid 1389 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Dec 02 16:16:32 2013] [notice] child pid 1390 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Dec 02 16:16:32 2013] [notice] child pid 1391 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Dec 02 16:16:32 2013] [notice] child pid 1392 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Dec 02 16:16:32 2013] [notice] child pid 1393 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Dec 02 16:16:34 2013] [notice] child pid 1394 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Dec 02 16:16:34 2013] [notice] child pid 1395 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Dec 02 16:16:34 2013] [notice] child pid 1396 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Mon Dec 02 16:16:34 2013] [notice] child pid 1397 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
...
```

And this goes one infinitely

Comment: Sounds like some caching problem. Try logging the actions and see what happens after 5 minutes after server restart.

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added the logs to the question

Comment: try this to get more info about your error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo

Comment: Apache is crashing. Please check the core generated by the crash for exact reason. You can enable core generation from bash shell by using command "ulimit -c unlimited".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  Changing the  memory_limit = 512M (from 128M) in the php.ini file then restarting Apache solved the problem.