# Why I have to restart apache every day (using zf2)?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2

I run in to a very strange problem while are developing a pretty simple zend application.
Every day again, when i first load the application in the browser I get an controller error (loads the template fine). After this error occurs it does not matter which page or URL I try to load, it just gives an initialization error while not even displaying the template.
If we SSH into the server and reboot apache, everything works fine again until the next day.

At first I thought it might have something to do with Directadmin updating the `PHP.ini` or something like that on any changes, but I have extensively tested this and it does not seem to have any influence.
For the record, I am running PHP 5.4 on CentOS.

Hopefully someone can help me with this issue or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Nothing showing up in the server error logs?

Comment: yes, the error log gives these errors on every page load:

[notice] child pid 31005 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Also, i am suspecting the error might occur for the first time after an unsuccesful route but i have to test this further

Comment: I might need to add, when i had this error for the first time restarting apache did not help. After editing the php.ini file and setting apc.enable_cli to 0 restarting apache did gave a temporary fix.

Comment: Based on the error you perhaps should be looking here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo

Comment: Yes, my search results have lead to posts like that. Fixing the APC did give me a temporary fix (aka when restarting apache it will work for the rest of the day). I have also checked the output buffering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone landing on this thread, i might have found the solution.

Not sure where the problem actually lies, but after rebuilding directadmin via Custombuild with the following commands my problem was solved:

./build all d

./build rewrite_confs

Answer (score 0):

The "Segmentation fault" is a critical error in Apache/PHP engine. If you encounter such error, you might need to install latest Apache/PHP updates with `yum update httpd php` command. Also, ensure you have the latest version of Zend Framework (run `php composer.php require zendframework/zendframework *` command and then run  `php composer.php update` command).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried this (again), but everything is already/still up-to-date

Comment: @AntoonCusell You might want to use remi-php55 repo to get latest php instead of very, very old 5.3.3 which is in default centos repos.

Comment: @Xerxus Thanks for the suggestion, i run directadmin.
Yesterday i have updated my php version from 5.4.17 to 5.4.29.
Unfortunately when trying today, it still gives the same problem.
Homepage loads fine (skeleton default page), then accessing the /login path it gives an initialization error upon which the homepage doesn't work anymore as well with the same initialization error.