# A PHP extension function give me core dump on linux, but same function work on Windows

Tags: php, linux, php-extension, coredump

I want to make a php extension on windows and also on linux, but i've got a function that give me core dump on linux, but on windows works.

```
PHP_FUNCTION(test_string)
{    
   char *arg = NULL;
   int arg_len, len;
   char string[256];

   if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &arg, &arg_len) == FAILURE) {
       return;
   }

   len = sprintf(string, "String:%s", arg);
   RETURN_STRINGL(arg, arg_len); 
}
```

[Tue Aug 30 11:53:26.504574 2016] [core:notice] [pid 22804] AH00051: child pid 22807 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /tmp/apache-coredumps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo

Comment: http://matrafox.info/apache-child-pid-exit-signal-segmentation-fault.html

Comment: What PHP version are you targeting? If PHP 7, then `arg_len` must be ? size_t`.