# Site not working on chrome but working on other browser of same machine

Tags: google-chrome

I have a site. Its not working on some machine (chrome but working on Firfox). Site is hosted on apache server.

Strange thing is that on other machine its working OK (all browser ).

I searched about this error on google/stackflow but did not get proper answer.

Any help

Answer (score 0):

Have you empty the cache of the browser or disable them (`Chrome -> F12 -> Network tab -> Disable cache`) and possibly the web site on the server if it uses some framework?

Do you use `.htaccess` with any restrictive rules?

What are the pages written in? Did you look at the Apache logs (errors, warnings)?

Comment: Yes I have cleared the cache. My site is build in Larvel. .htaccess file seems to OK as its working on other machine. I am facing this issue with chrome browser of some machine.. And  its working on other machine (all browser including chrome)  I checked the apache log and found following error [notice] child pid 6454 exit signal Segmentation fault (11). not sure if its related with this  --- the browser displaying following error --- ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Try this, It seems like simillar error [Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo)