# Wordpress works fine on admin dashboard but not loading for public

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, dns, root

My wordpress site posts are not loading but admin dashboard is accessible and public can access images as you can see here https://sevendiary.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Sheetal-Lama-Rai-My-life-as-Double-Decker-Bus-driver-in-London.jpg

Would be grateful if anyone can help me out why my main site is not showing up?

I get these replies when I run the following commands

1) `sudo tail -40 /var/log/apache2/error.log`

> AH00052: child pid 19235 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

2) `sudo service apache2 status`

```
Usage: apache2 {start|stop|graceful-stop|restart|reload|force-reload|start-htcacheclean|stop-htcacheclean}
```

And my resources limit is;

```
max_input_time = 60;
```

Maximum input variable nesting level

```
max_input_nesting_level = 64;
```

How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted

```
 max_input_vars = 1000;
```

Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)

```
memory_limit = -1
```

Comment: Have you made recent changes to the code or the server configuration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo

Comment: Ceejayoz, I tried setting up SSL certification on Google Clouds server from my end.

Comment: Did this start after those changes?

Comment: Thanks, the site is working fine now after uninstalling W3 Total Cache plugin. But the site SSL certification works with image links only and not posts.

Comment: Take a look at your browser's developer console for the reason for that. You're serving HTTP assets. `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://sevendiary.com/legendary-guitarist-yngwie-malmsteen-headline-2016-orange-festival-dambuk-arunachal-pradesh/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://35.194.159.165/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/logo1.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.`