# Apache server throwing Segmentation fault error for Wordpress 5 on PHP 7.3

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am trying to install `Wordpress 5` on `PHP 7.3` today on `Apache/2.4.37 (Ubuntu)` and it is constantly throwing errors like this:

> [Sun Dec 09 23:36:47.885206 2018] [core:notice] [pid 17094] AH00052:
>   child pid 17162 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

It's just redirecting to this page: `https://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php` without any response and above error in apache's error log.

What exactly is causing this and how can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["\[notice\] child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" in apache error.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo)

Answer (score 0):

disable xdebug if you have it enabled, while it comes out of beta for php7.3