# PHP Crash on echo

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault

**PLEASE IGNORE THIS QUESITON - I FOUND THAT THE PROBLEM DESCRIBED HERE IS NOT THE REAL PROBLEM.** 
thanks to those who tried to help.
The problem is gmagick specific. Not a general php issue.

I have this simple code on PHP Version 5.6.40-6+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+3

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$base_image = new Gmagick();
$base_image->newImage(3, 3, "#555555");
$base_image->setImageFormat('png');     
$x = $base_image->getImage();
echo $x;
?>
```

It works well (put out a 3x3 image) on ubuntu 16 php 5.6 server.
I've created a new Ubuntu 18.04 server from scratch with the same stack (details below) but it crashes on the **echo** statement.

> The error log shows: [Thu Apr 11 11:35:48.110542 2019] [core:notice]
>   [pid 9875] AH00051: child pid 10298 exit signal Segmentation fault
>   (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

What can cause such failure in the echo of a binary string representing an image?

See stack details here
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3968080/0606779cd806f2d6a6e02828dd643dfd

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($x)` to see if it's actually a binary string?

Comment: try doing var_dump or print_r instead of echo

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["\[notice\] child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" in apache error.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo)

Comment: @RahulMeshram  Interesting . var_dump gives object(Gmagick)#2 (0) { }
It shows the same thing also on the older server which works.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa  var_dump gives object(Gmagick)#2 (0) { } It shows the same thing also on the older server which works.

Answer (score 0):

I am referring to this [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimage.php).

so `var_dump($x);` should give you a proper solution as it's object not string.

Returns a new Gmagick object with the current image sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It's an Imagick object. You can convert it to string like:

```
$x::getImageBlob()
```

see in: https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageblob.php

Comment: I changed to getImageBlob();
Now it gives me a string in the working server and NULL in the non working one.