# Apache PHP error AH00052 Segmentation fault 11

Tags: php, apache, php-7

I'm working on my local Mac Catalina environment with PHP 7.4.8 with apache installed. There is the PHP 7.3 version that got installed with Catalina which I haven't removed. I overwritten apache config in httpd.conf to point the PHP version to the 7.4 that got installed with brew.  I am trying to upload a vendor bill using the Netsuite SDK but keep getting this error in the apache error log:

```
[Wed Aug 05 11:43:30.001427 2020] [core:notice] [pid 7195] AH00052: child pid 25656 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Aug 05 11:43:30.002166 2020] [core:notice] [pid 7195] AH00052: child pid 25655 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Aug 05 11:43:30.002207 2020] [core:notice] [pid 7195] AH00052: child pid 25654 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Aug 05 11:43:30.002236 2020] [core:notice] [pid 7195] AH00052: child pid 25526 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Aug 05 11:43:31.003428 2020] [core:notice] [pid 7195] AH00052: child pid 33510 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Aug 05 11:43:32.003629 2020] [core:notice] [pid 7195] AH00052: child pid 33511 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

The bill works (I dump out the object) until I try to send it up to Netsuite and then I get a "This page isn't working" with `AH00052` in the apache error logs. I can send up a Credit memo just fine but Vendor Bill just isn't working so it's just this. Things I've tried:

**UPDATE**

1. I increased the `output_buffering` to 8192M, 8192, Off and -1. Thanks to [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo)
2. I tried to turn off `output_buffering`.
3. I saw that my terminal and phpinfo were displaying two different versions. Got that updated in apache to point to the new PHP version.
4. Tried turning off memory limit too.

I saw comments about PHP and PHP-FPM being different in versions. When I run `-v` on both php and fpm, it shows the same version. I don't have any other super fancy packages installed. I have a Wordpress site also installed locally just fine so apache is working. It's just something that's causing this error. I got m

I've spent days on debugging this. I appreciate any feedback. I've attached a pic of what phpinfo spits out. [image: Attached is a pic of the phpinfo();]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["\[notice\] child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" in apache error.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo)

Comment: Have you checked this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199561/apache-and-php-not-working-child-pid-xxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov that was the forum that lead me to the output_buffering. I added an M to it then got a memory limit warning. Set that to -1. Restarted Apache again and getting the same error.

Comment: but do you use mod_php or php-fpm? I would tend to say mod_php as php crashes the Apache process, it means it's the same big process. php-fpm would crash the php instance only.

Comment: @Capsule you know, I really don't know. I think I am just using mod_php because this one website said 'FastCGI' would show up in the server API setting in the ini. I haven't had to restart apache at all--except when change settings of course. Do you think I need to see if FPM is being used?

Comment: it doesn't really matter as long as you can determine which user it's running as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this will help anyone. I switched from apache to nginx with php-fpm and was still getting 503 blocks. After weeks of randomly look into this, I found out that Netsuite's documentation on VendorBill was wrong. There was one property that according to the documentation required an object. When I pulled down an existing vendor bill and compared it to what I was trying to push up, I realized that one of the properties was actually a string--not an object. This was causing the 503. There was absolutely no error except in the nginx/apache logs that mentioned something about an issue upstream. That was all.

I hope this helps someone. I recommend that if you need to send up something new like a vendor bill and are having trouble, pull down an existing one and compare what you're trying to push up to what you were able to pull down.