# PHP - this site can't be reached ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, mongodb, apache

### What's the problem?

Hello, I've got problem with my Apache server (I'm using PHP). Everything like redirecting, serving views - all simple operations works fine. However when I'm trying to do something more 'complicated', for example connect to MongoDB or use `phpinfo()` function, then the browser shows only the blank page with the header - `This Site can't be reached ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

In the `var/log/apache2/error.log` file it shows this error message everytime it shows the blank page:

> child pid < some number here > exit signal Segmentation Fault (11)

### What could caused the problem?

So all this problems starts to happen after I was trying to install mongodb drivers for PHP and did some operations. It was showing me this error:

> mongodb/mongodb 1.8.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.8.1 -> the requested PHP
> extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.2.3) installed

So I did a couple of things after reading on internet how to solve this problem:

- I added the `extension=mongo.so` in `php.ini` file
- I used `sudo apt install php-dev` to enable `pecl` command (becouse I couldn't use it before)
- Then I entered this command to update all mongodb extensions: `sudo pecl install mongodb`
- And I required mongodb using composer in my project folder

And after all this steps, I have this 'blank page' problem.
I uninstalled `php-dev` but of course it didn't change nothing. I couldn't find similar problem to mine on internet.

Comment: What happen when you comment/remove the `extension=mongo.so` line from php.ini?

Comment: @bpanatta it changes nothing, the problem still occurs

Comment: First, check out [What is a segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2346849/2282634).  Memory accesses are often very difficult to debug.  Try making the logs more verbose for both [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel) to see if you can determine what exactly was happening when the segfault occurred.

Comment: @Joe could you recommend me something where I can read more about making my logs more verbose?

Comment: @maniek2213 Take a look at this and see if will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745578/notice-child-pid-xxxx-exit-signal-segmentation-fault-11-in-apache-error-lo