# PHP zend_mm_heap corrupted

Tags: php, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “zend_mm_heap corrupted” mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247977/what-does-zend-mm-heap-corrupted-mean)

Good afternoon.

There is a problem in a large project. In the apache logs written error:

> [Tue Jan 24 15:06:32 2012] [notice] child pid 24326 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   zend_mm_heap corrupted
>   [Tue Jan 24 15:09:02 2012] [notice] child pid 24485 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>   zend_mm_heap corrupted
>   zend_mm_heap corrupted

and there are many.

How can you catch in any PHP script this error and what url?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a PHP language error, you will not catch it inside PHP script, or with a specific URL.

This is the Zend memory manager **crashing**, i.e. the internals of the PHP module itself.

[Also you should learn to search before asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247977/what-does-zend-mm-heap-corrupted-mean) - Or at least tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Usually the problem shows under load, after about 30-40 requests per second.
Disabling APC does not help.

But the code is using "unset" for arrays. By trying to remove them.