# Small program crashing..crashes with different errors and at different times

Tags: php, zend-framework, simple-html-dom

For some reason this program keeps crashing with zend_mm_heap error also getting zend_hash_destroy() error. Any ideas? I can not find much on the net about this, have asked on irc and they have no idea either. I did read other threads about this and have tried those work arounds, but nothing works for me.

```
    <?
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

getAlluc();

function getAlluc(){
    $url = 'http://www.alluc.org/';
    $movieLinks = array();
    $tvLinks = array();
    $animeLinks = array();
    $cartoonLinks = array();
    $documentaryLinks = array();
$musicClipLinks = array();
$sportLinks = array();
$html = setPage($url."/movies.html");
foreach($html->find('a[class$=linklist_header]') as $movies){
    $ml = str_replace("&amp;","&",$movies->href);
    echo $ml."\n";
    array_push($movieLinks,$url.$ml);
}

//get actual movie links below

foreach($movieLinks as $letter){
    echo $letter."\n";
    $html = setPage($letter);
    foreach($html->find('li.linklist2') as $li){
            foreach($li->find('a[href]') as $href){
                echo $href->href."\n".$href->plaintext."\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

function setPage($url){

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url);
    return $html;
}

?>
```

Comment: What are the exact error messages ?

Comment: zend_mm_heap() and zend_hash_destory() seg 11

Comment: It might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247977/what-does-zend-mm-heap-corrupted-mean and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832010/what-is-output-buffering/2832179#2832179

Comment: I read both of them already and have increased my OPB to an insane number and it actually made it crash earlier in the execution then at the standard 4096

Comment: What version of PHP and libxml are you using?  Have you tried commenting out blocks of code until you find which line causes the crash? Maybe that will help a bit, could be a bug or inconsistency between libraries.

Comment: I have tried commenting out code, I did not supply all the code for the program except on where the crash was occurring.. just formatted my computer, will respond back when all software is back in place

Comment: Running PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2   libxml Version 2.7.8