# segmentation fault 11 in apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, segmentation-fault

i am running 3 wordpress sites on an amazon instance. have also installed a varnish cache for one of these sites. config - centOS + apache + php + mysql . however i keep getting these errors twice or thrice in a day

[Sat Aug 10 19:10:42 2013] [notice] child pid 4481 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Aug 10 20:15:27 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Aug 10 20:15:27 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sat Aug 10 20:15:28 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Aug 10 20:15:28 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Aug 10 20:15:28 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations

so when i check my website after this has happened it returns 500. although at this point the httpd is running. when i restart the httpd again then everything works fine. Sometimes instead of segmentation fault (11), the error is - zend_mm_heap corrupted

Its a really vexing issue why this keeps happening. Hoping someone could suggest something...

Answer (score 0):

This question also refers to the zend_mm_heap corrupted error: [What does "zend_mm_heap corrupted" mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247977/what-does-zend-mm-heap-corrupted-mean) . It suggest that you increment the output_buffering= value in the php.ini. You might give that a shot.

If that doesn't help, do you have some kind of statistics about memory usage of the server. Might it be that memory is full? Also is there anything to be found in the PHP error log from around the time that these errors occur?