# I cannot run PHPUnit

Tags: php, magento, phpunit

i have a problem with PHPUnit. I installed it using PEAR, no problems there, but when i try to run a test (which should work because it works for a friend) i get an error which i cannot resolve:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536890912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 504627201 bytes) in my/path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 644
>
> zend_mm_heap corrupted

I increased the memory limit in my php.ini files (in apache and php) and the only result was that i had to wait longer for the error to appear. I am using WAMP with Apache 2.2.22 and php 5.3.13 and PHPUnit 1.3.2. I tried all i could think of and i couldn't find any solution yet.

Comment: Just because something works for a friend does not mean it should work for you. Start by examining the differences between your setup and theirs.

Comment: the thing is that there are none. We have same type of laptop, same OS, made the same steps to install it, running the same configuration and everything

Comment: Based on the new info you have just added it sounds like it could be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247977/what-does-zend-mm-heap-corrupted-mean

Comment: did you try increasing output_buffering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is  memory limit is arising this problem. You can change max_execution_time, max_input_time and memory_limit = 512M in the php.ini and in the .htaccess file to fix this problem.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/38843/

Comment: Thank you for your prompt responses, i have already tried your link and Anigel's, still no success

Comment: I finally managed to get it to work, there was a problem with my DB, and the error i got was just too big (i think). i even tried to put it in the log but that didn't work either. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

if you have enough RAM, you can use unlimited amount of memory :*

```
<!-- phpunit.xml -->
<php>
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1" />
</php>
```