# Page not available when using SplFixedArray

Tags: php, oop, pdo, resultset

I'm getting "Page not available" if I run the following code:

```
namespace Database;
class Table extends \Database\Connection {
    // ...

    /**
     * Execute query and return result
     * @param type $query
     * @param type $sqlWildcards
     * @return SplFixedArray ResultSet
     */
    public static function query($query, $sqlWildcards = array()) {
        // Do some query stuff
        // $stmt is a PHP PDO Statement

        // Additional result manipulation
        $rowCount = 0;
        $rsStorage = new \SplFixedArray(500000);
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $modRow = static::modifyRow($row);
            if ($modRow !== false) {
                $rsStorage[$rowCount] = $modRow;
                $rowCount++;
            }
        }

        // Resize 
        $rsStorage->setSize($rowCount);
    }
}
```

**Method modifyRow($row):**

```
/**
 * Gives the possibility to modify a result for child classes 
 * @param array $row
 * @return array
 */
protected static function modifyRow($row) {
    return $row;
}
```

<strike>But if I do the following:</strike>

```
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        //$modRow = static::modifyRow($row);
        //if ($modRow !== false) {
            $rsStorage[$rowCount] = $modRow;
            $rowCount++;
        //}
    }
```

Everything works fine!

**Edit:** The test above makes no sense, I forgot to set $modRow to $row - this fails as well.

Another hint: if I do something like  this

```
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $modRow = static::modifyRow($row);
        if ($modRow !== false) {
            $rsStorage[$rowCount] = $modRow;
            $rowCount++;
        }

        // Works
        if($rowCount == 5000) { break; }

        // Crashes (Page not available
        if($rowCount == 10000) { break; }
    }
```

Error reporting is activated but there's no internal server error, though. Just "page not available"

**Edit:** 9742 is the magic number. When $rowCount hits 9743 it crashes - doesn't matter if I test it from 0 to 9743 or 9744 to x

**Edit2:** If I use array instead of SplFixedArray everything's fine. Does not make sense since splfixedarray is more memory efficient than array()

**Edit3:** I wrote the memory usage into a file until the script crashes, it reaches a peak of 54MB - server limit is 128MB

**Edit4:** Apache log shows me a 'zend_mm_heap corrupted'

Never had this before, also google could not help me
Any idea?

Comment: This code is inside a class right?

Comment: Yes, its kind of a PHP PDO wrapper for additional stuff

Comment: Your "everything works" actually adds null (?) to the array, not the row. And if 5000 works but not 10000 then it looks like a memory problem?

Comment: but a memory problem would throw an internal server error, wouldn't it? I'm getting "page not available" and why does it work if I do not use the placeholder method "modifyRow"?

Comment: In your example which works $modRow is perhaps undefined (depending on code above). Even if it has a value it always adds the same value in memory to the array.

Comment: but how can it be undefined if I pass a PHP PDO ResultSet row (with fetch_assoc) to a method that just simply returns $row?

Comment: Your code which "works" has commented out that part. Add a dump and exit after 5 iterations of the loops for simple debugging.

Comment: I tested it with 5 example results, printing it before and after modifyRow, it's 1:1 the same.

Comment: You are not reading my messages... Try with your "working" example which commented out this part: //$modRow = static::modifyRow($row); - but kept this the same: $rsStorage[$rowCount] = $modRow;

Comment: I dont see where `$stmt` is defined, and is that all :modifyRow code does

Comment: It is defined as described in my code comments. It's not part of the issue that's why I have not included it. The query is fine, the results are fine as well - I will provide some test data tomorrow.

Comment: I added 2 edits to my post. First of all: my working test does not work since I forgot to change $modRow to $row - also I found out when everything crashes (second edit)

Comment: I tested array() instead of SplFixedArray(int $size) to check memory issues and it works. But this does not make sense to me, SplFixedArray is much more efficient than array(), both should not work..

Comment: I added a memory peak test - it reaches 54MB until it crashes, server limit is 128MB

Comment: There ought to be an error log with a productive error message somewhere. The "not available" response your web server is fronting is not useful in debugging this. Figure out where your error logs are.

Comment: Apache throws 'zend_mm_heap corrupted' - I searched for a solution and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247977/what-does-zend-mm-heap-corrupted-mean - I tried to increase the output_buffer but this does not work for me