# zend_mm_heap corrupted ERROR crashing app server

Tags: php, apache, server, lamp

I have encountered "zend_mm_heap corrupted" Error on my app server.
error_log trace is below

```
[Fri Oct 16 23:25:57 2015] [error] [client  "client ip"] zend_mm_heap corrupted
[Fri Oct 16 23:25:57 2015] [error] [client  "client ip"] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Fri Oct 16 23:25:57 2015] [error] [client  "client ip"] zend_mm_heap corrupted
[Fri Oct 16 23:25:57 2015] [error] [client  "client ip"] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Fri Oct 16 23:25:58 2015] [error] [client  "client ip"] zend_mm_heap corrupted, referer: http://domain/
[Fri Oct 16 23:25:58 2015] [error] [client  "client ip"] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://domain/
[Fri Oct 16 23:25:58 2015] [error] [client  "client ip"] zend_mm_heap corrupted, referer: http://domain/
[Fri Oct 16 23:25:58 2015] [error] [client  "client ip"] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://domain/
```

I tried different approach bu no luck. Any Idea how this problem can be fixed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "zend\_mm\_heap corrupted" mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247977/what-does-zend-mm-heap-corrupted-mean)

Comment: I don't think so @Luminous. Before posting I worked around with the solutions given in other posts. But no luck. coz I dont have OPchache and APC in my server.

Answer (score 0):

**Update :** Issue is resolved now.
Made two changes in app server to clear the issues.
One reinstalled the frame work used in the server. that resolved the issue of zend_mm_heap.

Secondly removed unwanted extension of homeloader.so from php.ini to end the error of Premature end of script headers: index.php.